# Correct way to add labels for RISCV data section (so assembler can pick up)

Tags: assembly, gcc, riscv, gnu-assembler

The assembler translated the access to first label in `.data` section with no problem, but the subsequent labels to some `gp` relative address, which if I don't get what's the purpose for.

I'm trying to write a simple riscv assembly program that would have some array operations (I think allocate in .data section)

It's as simple as it could get, allocated spaces, for example, need to have .data section and .rodata section, I'd have

```
.section .rodata     <---- **okay access**
.align 2
sentence1:
  .string "Sentence number one\n"
.align 2
sentence2:
  .string "Sentence number two\n"

.section .data
.align 2
num1:               <---- **okay access**
  .word 0
num2:               <---- **can't find**
  .word 0
.align 2
arr:                <---- **can't find**
  .space 1024

.section .text
__start:
<my program logic>
```

I'm using the RISCV-toolchain's assembler:

```bash
riscv64-unknown-elf-as -v
GNU assembler version 2.40.0 (riscv64-unknown-elf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.40.0.20230214
```

The problem is, when executing it always segfaulted where begin to access anything after the first label in the `.data` section, the first label, `num1` in this case, translated fine, also anything in `.rodata` such as `sentence1` and `sentence2` also can be accessed

by **accessed** I mean the address can be found, through instructions such as:

```
la   a0, num1
```

or

```
auipc  a0, %hi(num1)
addi   a0, %lo(num1)
```

then having load and store such as `lw` or `sw` on `a0` would have no problem.

The problem arises when trying to access anything in `.data` (not `.rodata`, `.rodata` has no problem!) that is after the first label, such as `num2` or `arr`.

When I run the program in gdb to find what's going on, viewing the execution of each assembly line, it translated the first access to the address into a pair of `auipc` and `addi` to get the correct address (for `num1`), but after that, getting subsequent addresses are translated into an `addi` instruction using `gp` global pointer.

Which, since I either linked with just `ld` with no library and no `crt0.o`, `crtstart.o` or `gcc` telling `--nostartfiles` and `--nostdlib`. I think it's maybe something going on there setting up the `gp`? or is `gp` reference is just means something that the assembler can't pick up?

I try to write up some C code with the similar intent and structure and did `gcc -S` and in its output file, it allocated the spaces for those labels using more than just a name and space, but a
combination of `.local .comm` such as:

```
.local sum1
.comm sum1, 4, 4
```

(I had `sum1` as a file scope static variable, if removed the `static`, I think it would have `.globl .comm .type .size` things)

Are they in charge of **emiting** (I actually don't really known what this word means) the labels so the assembler can pick the symbol up and translate into the correct address? If I don't want to use `.comm` but just write `.word` or `.byte`, how should I emit (?) the address?

Or somewhere else in my theory is wrong?

Comment: What asm source lines are you writing to access static storage that's getting the assembler to invent usage of the `gp` register?  That would make a [mcve].  Your manual `auipc`/ `addi` with `%hi`/`%lo` shouldn't be using `gp`.  (And BTW, you can use `%lo` as the offset in an `lw`, without the separate `addi` to compute the final address in a register.  For debugging it can be helpful to have the full address in a register you can check, but it's less efficient.)

Comment: Thank you, I think @droptop's answer answered my problem as it's the problem of `ld`'s default relaxation rule without linking the correct startfile that sets up the global pointer.

From the objdump of the `.o` files, the address has no problem, but the binaries produced by `ld` has the same instruction in `.rodata` access but not `.data` access as I described.

Comment: That would have been useful info to put in the question in the first place to make it clear things were changing during the linking step.  And exactly how they were changing, from what to what.  Probably a good idea to still add that, since other people searching for the same problem might search on the `(%gp)` part of the addressing-mode.  (But the numeric part will depend on the case so it's not maybe not perfect for helping searches find out about linker relaxations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're having trouble with an uninitialized global pointer.

The default linker script (which is used when you do not pass one to `ld` with the `-T` argument) defines `__global_pointer`, whose value is supposed to be used to initialize `gp`. This initialization is usually done in startup files that don't get linked with `-nostartfiles`.

So you can either do away with this flag, or setup `gp` yourself right at the start of `.text`, like so,

```
.option push
.option norelax
la gp, __global_pointer$
.option pop
```

Using `gp` instead of an `auipc + addi` pair to access symbols in `.data` is called linker relaxation, and is done because `ld` encountered a definition of  `__global_pointer&` in the linker script. You can read more about it [here](https://www.five-embeddev.com//quickref/global_pointer.html)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Actually when I was just writing this question halfway, I was like "let me objdump the (working) binary compiled by gcc and see"

and I saw crt0.o, and then I saw the gp was set up there to point to BSS (or something like that), and then from there i did a little research and saw this:

https://maskray.me/blog/2021-03-14-the-dark-side-of-riscv-linker-relaxation#global-pointer-relaxation

which, I now understand what's going on

Comment: My get around is to pass `--no-relax` as a flag to `ld`. It is interesting to see how `.option` works, can you point me where to reference to those `.option` things and how to use?